# Need to change Ubuntu Server IP config with Asterisk PBX installed

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04 running with Asterisk 11.5.0 and I need to change my public IP to a new one.

Do I just need to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` configurations or do I need to change Asterisk configuration as well?